Login with AJAX and Open Redirect Vulnerability
I have a ASP.NET Core 8 MVC project where user login is an AJAX request that if successfull redirects user to "home" (or another internal page).
This situation made SNYK trigger an "Open Redirect" issue to me:

Unsanitized input from data from a remote resource flows into
window.location, where it is used as an URL to redirect the user. This
may result in an Open Redirect vulnerability.

But how should I address this, since I must move the user within my system? Making this a
AJAX request:
$.ajax({
    url: '/Login',
    type: 'POST',
    async: true,
    data: {
        __RequestVerificationToken: token,
    },
    success: function (response) {
        if (response != null && response.success)
            window.location.href = response.redirectURL;
    }
});


This warning tell you avoid using the window.location.href with variable, since this response.redirectURL. If you make sure this redirecrulr will static redirect to home page, I suggest you could directly using the  window.location.href = "\".
